# PHP SQL using query results from one page in query in another

Tags: php, sql

In my first page I have
I have a query that returns tournaments names in a table in this format

```
echo "<td><a href='tournament.php'>" . $info['tournament'] . "</a></td>";
```

$info['tournament'] has the tournament name which when clicked takes me to the page tournament.php where I have this code

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT team1,score1,team2,score2 FROM table where tournament='';") or die(mysql_error());
```

what i want is to have the value clicked in the previous page that linked to this one, in `tournament='HERE'` so that the query retrieve the data for that tournament

Comment: Look up `$_GET` and `PDO`, don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Doing what you suggest without sanitizing the input would cause a SQLi vulnerability. I won't post full code for you for your own good, you need to do some reading. I'm sure someone else will though, but you should still do some reading.

Comment: my bad I thought that people who are new to coding can come here and ask questions to help them learn thank you for the advice and the vote down.

Comment: I'm guessing you were offended by my comment. That was not my intent at all, I was just giving you some well meant advice as I think you would benefit from doing some research on the topic on your own in the long run. I didn't down vote by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create ID for the tournament if you haven't already (I mean in the table) - it's a good practice. Then, you would have a link like this:

```
echo "<td><a href='tournament.php?id=".$info['id']."'>" . $info['tournament'] . "</a></td>";
```

Then, about your query: [mysql functions are deprecated from PHP 5.5, and you are strongly encouraged to use PDO statements or mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php).

But for that lesson, you would use something like that (read about filtering - in this case `intval()`:

```
$tournament_id = intval($_GET['id']);
if($tournament_id > 0)
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT team1,score1,team2,score2 FROM table where id = ".$tournament_id.";") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by create ID for tournament ? the table has many random tournaments some of them are repeated because each one has many matches in it the table goes like this (matchid,team1,score1,team2,score2,tournament) matchid is a random int

Comment: Create new column in the table with tournaments called `id`, give it attribute `AUTO_INCREMENT` and integer as a type.

Comment: the matchid is the primary key it is a random integer each tournament can have many matches so there is no way to id each tournament the table has almost 500 matches

Comment: Oh well, then you should have 2 tables. One for tournaments `tournaments(id, name)` and second one for matches `matches(id, tournament, team1, team2, score1, score2)`. Both `id` for primary keys and tournament in `matches` should be a foreign key.

Comment: so I have created ID column in both tables and did what you said I can see the tournament id in the url, however the query returns empty and and when I print $tournamentName it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

You can change the link to supply the tournament name (or, even better, an id):

```
echo "<td><a href='tournament.php?tournament=".$info['tournament']."'>" . $info['tournament'] . "</a></td>";
```

In tournament.php you can now access tournament via:

```
$tournamentName = $_GET['tournament'];//Remember to check if it exists
```

You can then use `$tournamentName` in your query. Please remember to escape `$tournamentName` since it may contain malicious values.

Also consider switching from the `mysqli_*` functions. These are now deprecated. Consider `PDO` or `mysqli`. When switching to these it's also a good idea to look into prepared statements.

Comment: what do you mean escape? sorry I am new to this

Comment: @user3386406 No need to apologise, everyone was new at some point. Escaping means removing or making safe any dangerous values. See [mysql_real_escape](http://uk1.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) (although as I mentioned I reccommend switching to `PDO` or `mysqli`). The reason for this is that a user could type SQL into the GET parameter and your query will run the SQL.

Comment: for some reason its not working for me I can see in the url the tournament name with %20 between each word but when I try to echo %tournamentname it comes out empty

Comment: @user3386406 What do you see if you do `print_r($_GET)`?

Comment: Array ( [tournament] => Clash of the Gods ) which is strange because the tournament i clicked was (Clash of the Gods #1 - Challonge)

Comment: That's why i posted my solution (:

Comment: @user3386406 But you say `$tournamentName` is empty? Are you sure?

Comment: sorry i had a type it is returing the tournament but without the # and numbers and the query in tournament.php returns empty

Comment: The thing is, you can have many titles which will have special characters like # in your case. Browser won't send anchor part to your $_GET as default. You might find yourself in a situation with many other characters in names like ' or /.

Comment: @user3386406 You can `urlencode($info['tournament'] )` when adding it to the link. However as I alluded to (and @ailvenge mentions) it's better to us an id if you have one available.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to pass tournament to next page using get method

```
echo "<td><a href='tournament.php?tournament=" . $info['tournament'] . "'>".$info['tournament'] . "</a></td>";
```

and get on second page using this code

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT team1,score1,team2,score2 FROM table where tournament='" . $_GET['tournament'] . "';") or die(mysql_error());
```

hope you get points...